# opening colorbox from php

Tags: php, include, colorbox

i have a problem with my php section.

I have a registration form .php and would like to have a response
message after submitting in an iframe colorbox.
I have a seperate response .php which is up to now included in  the
registration form .php. till now it will be displayed in a table with
include-once response .php. Thats not very nice to see so i want that to
open in a colorbox.

I´m new in that business and searched for answers for a long time but
without success.

So is there anybody who can help me please. My thought was to echo an
url with the response .php instead of include-once response .php but
it doesnt work. next thing i thought was to add something like a
-class iframe link to url- like in html body where i use colorbox for
terms and conditions.

i would really appreciate if there is someone who can help. thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using? Anyway, you might need a js event to fire (onsubmit,onclick..) and attach the colorbox to it..Just guessing, though

Answer (score 1):

Well...you are confusing client- and severside-actions. Be aware that colorbox is something that runs on the client, not the server. Therefore you need to change the behavior of your page.

**Version 1**

When your form has been submitted use your response PHP-file to output JavaScript code that will open a colorbox once the document finished loading. Something like this:

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['submitted'])): ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         // open your colorbox here
    });
 </script>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

**Version 2**

Replace your standard form by an AJAX solution. When the submit button is clicked, use jQuery to do an AJAX request to your respone PHP file. This way you can show a colorbox while the request is being processed and once it's finished, you can hide the colorbox, show another one or whatever you like.

You can find loads of instructions on how to do AJAX requests with jQuery either here on SO or in the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

**Version 3**

The ugliest solution would be to use JavaScript to open a colorbox containing an iframe and then submitting the form to this iframe using `target="iframename`" in the `<form>` tag. That is probably the closest solution to what you describe that you want to do, but it is also the ugliest one of all possibilities. ;)

Comment: hallo, habe gerade gesehen, dass sie aus dresden kommen. war das englisch quasi umsonst. ich habe mich hier neu angemeldet und dachte, es wäre eine amerikanische seite. es wäre sehr nett von ihnen, wenn sie mir vielleicht bei meiner antwort behilflich sein könnten um mein verständnisproblem zu lösen. vielen dank und beste grüße aus berlin

Comment: Well...it's a website and that is by definition international. And as SO is meant to be a collection of questions and answers for everyone to browse when searching a solution for their problems, it's custom to writing English so everyone can benefit from the knowlege.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the form using ajax and write the message to display in ajax calling page and show that message in colorbox on the same page..

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
$.ajax({
                'type':'post',
                'data':formData ,
                'url':'action-page-url.php',
                'cache':false,
                'success':function(r){
                          $("body").append("<div id='response'></div>");
                          $("#response").hide().html(r).colorbox();
                          }
       });   
return false; // To override non-ajax submitting
});
```

Answer (score 1):

okay,

thanks for answering my question.

i found a code for the ajax solution from someone who had nearly the same problem:

```
$("#link").colorbox({ inline:true, href: "#msg"});
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "form.php",
      data: $('intpu[type="text"]').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          $("#msg").html(data);
          $("#link").click(); 
          return false;
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

and the html code

```
<form name="exam" method="post">
      <input size="60" type="text" name="quote" />
      <input type="submit"> 
</form>
<a id="link" style="display:none"></a>
<div id="msg" style="display:none;"></div>
```

i think it is not the best way to implement the response message to the body. everybody who looks at the source code of the page could read the response message. i would prefera server hiden version with php like the first version but it doesnt work. when i will open the colorbox without a selector like

```
$.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"msgToUser.php"
```

that will open the colorbox after click submit but the #message that is integrated in the response. php file will not be displayed. another problem is that when i´m going to submit the form and there will be an error because of missing entry the colorbox will be opened as well.

best wishes from berlin, germany.

Comment: A little advice: You may answer your own question...no problem. But only if it's actually an answer. If you have additional questions either edit your initial post and add your new questions or create another question. This is not a forum and posting more questions as an answer is rather confusing. :)